# Terminology am I doing a one to many or many to many? Left join? Right?

Tags: sql, join

I need to research this but am confused about the terminology of what I should be researching.

Table1 fields:

```
salenumber  
category    
quantity    
price
```

Table2 fields:

```
field   
category    
requirement
```

Table3 fields:

```
field   
salenumber  
value
```

I need to combine these.

Essentially one (salenumber, category, quantity, Price) can have a dynamic number of "fields" containing unique "data associated with it. I'm a little confused as to the terminology of what I am doing here. I'm all mixed up with left and right joins and many to one and many to many databases. If I simply knew the term for what I am trying to do it would help me to narrow down my research.

Comment: The relationship between Table1,Table3 appears to be one-to-many, because each field in Table3 has a `salenumber` referring to Table1. It is unclear how or if Table2 relates to Table3 though (and more clear how Table2 relates to Table1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins are for your queries - which you run to find specific records from your database. You aren't there yet. First, you want to do table design, which is where you consider many-to-many and one-to-many relationships.

Start by thinking about what the tables represent. For example, a single sale can involve multiple different products (e.g. you buy a fork, a spoon, a knife, and a new car). Each product can be in a different category (utensils or motor vehicles, in this case). In your table design, you would decide whether a product belongs to only a single category or to multiple categories.

Let's assume there's just one category per product - then you can have many products in one category (fork, spoon and knife are all utensils), but a product can have only one category. In this case, Category to Product is a One-to-Many relationship.

How these connect is where the related fields in tables come in to play - so in the Product table you have 'Category', which refers to the Category table ('Fork' is of Category 'Utensil', and in the Category table 'Utensil' is an entry with additional information).

You probably want to look up some basic database lessons to help you out. There are some good free online classes and resources - just search for info about databases.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. This specific instance is for inventory actually. So quantity and price fields are always there. However inventory specific fields are variable. So say for a computer I may have fields like "cpu" "ram" "hard drive" but for a camera i might have "Battery" "megapixels" "storage". I was trying to figure out a way to have a variable number of fields for item specifics and this is where I was headed.

Answer (score 0):

This may help understand joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

If you have a row in Table_A with some id,  and multiple rows in `Table_B` related referencing that id you can do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (often just `LEFT JOIN`).  This will match the data in `Table_A` to `Table_B` - but you will have as many rows as there were in `Table_B`!

If you want all of the `Table_B` data related to the `Table_A` row in one row result you need an aggregate function.  In SQL this is normally something like `array_agg`.  When you do this you need to tell it what to `GROUP BY`,  in my example it would be `Table_A.id`

Comment: Thank you. That visual definitely helps.